# issue with Tagging system - duplicate images

Tags: php, mysql

I have a comics site and have implemented a tagging system similar to that of StackOverflow's.

I wanted to give users more sorting options by introducing a SO-style tagging system - each user can select and remove 1 or many tags... each comic id is associated to 1 or many tags.

The goals are:

- Function will display all comics if no category and no tags are chosen
- If category x is selected, will display only that category's comics
- If category x AND tag x is selected, will display all comics in category x AND tag x
- If NO category is selected, but tags x, y, z are selected, function will display only those comics associated with those tags

I'm using a relational table to check if there's a matching imgid to the selected tagids.

So in the database, in order for the image to be associated to multiple tags (which it should be able to), I have to add the same imgid again, with a different tagid.

[image]

Here's the query:

```
    $sql = 
     "SELECT tbl.*, t.* 
     FROM $table tbl 
     LEFT JOIN $assocTable a ON (tbl.id = a.imgID) 
     LEFT JOIN $tagsTable t ON (t.tagid = a.tagID) 
     WHERE "; 

    $sql .= !empty($_SESSION[$sessiontagIDs]) ? "a.tagID IN (" . implode(', ', $_SESSION[$sessiontagIDs]). ") " : "1 = 1"; 
    $sql .= $catquery ." " . $order;
```

Unfortunately, that means that a comic is now showing twice from the query:

[image]

Do I have the tables or query set up incorrectly?

Thank you!

Comment: +1 for using graphics to make question clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are fetching the comic for every tag that it matches.  Perhaps you want the query to get:

```
select distinct tbl.*
. . .
```

Or, if you want the tags at the same time, use `group_concat()` to get them in a list:

```
select tbl.*, group_concat(t.tagname)
. . .
group by tbl.id
```

Comment: thanks for the thoughts, Gordon. `group_concat(t.tagname)` only returns one image at a time, even though many or all tags have been selected. What did you mean by "if I want the tags at the same time"?  `distinct tbl.*` seems to work fine :) Can you explain a bit why that works?

Comment: In your original query, you were including the tags in the `select` statement.  For images that had more than one tag, there would be duplicates.  By removing the tags from the `select` line, the `distinct` can remove the duplciates.